# How do I simply add two decimal places and round to the nearest two decimal places?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

**The first picture is what my professor wants us to do:**
https://prnt.sc/v1drxs

**Here is MY code:**

```
Console.Write("Enter the radius for a circle: ");

double radius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
double diameter = 2 * radius;
double circumference = Convert.ToDouble(Math.PI * diameter);

Console.WriteLine("\nThe radius of the circle is " + radius + " units.");
Console.WriteLine("The diameter of the circle is " + diameter + " units.");
Console.WriteLine("The circumference of the circle is " + circumference + " units.");

Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");

Console.ReadKey();
```

**What I have tried:**

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. I'm very new to coding. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's the output do you get with this code? what's the output do you want instead? Can you share some example input and output of your code?

Comment: You may want to look a... `Math.Round(myDoubleValue, 2)`

Comment: https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Math.Round(myDouble, 2)` to round the value to two decimal places.

However, if the value rounds such that the decimal values are “X.00”, then this will output “X”

From what I can tell you want it to output “X.00”

For this, we can use the `String.Format` method.

Below is an example of the 3 cases.

```
Console.WriteLine("The radius of the circle is " + radius + " units.");
Console.WriteLine("The diameter of the circle is " + diameter + " units.");
Console.WriteLine("The circumference of the circle is " + circumference + " units.");

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("The radius of the circle is " + Math.Round(radius, 2) + " units");
Console.WriteLine("The diameter of the circle is " + Math.Round(diameter, 2) + " units"); 
Console.WriteLine("The circumference of the circle is " + Math.Round(circumference, 2) + " units");

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The radius of the circle is {0:0.00} units", Math.Round(radius, 2)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The diameter of the circle is {0:0.00} units", Math.Round(diameter, 2)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The circumference of the circle is {0:0.00} units", Math.Round(circumference, 2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use *interpolated strings* with *format specifiers*.  By prefacing a string with a `$` dollar sign, you signal the compiler that the string contains variables within `{}` braces that need substitution.  The `F2` format specifier says "show this to two decimal places" (the `F` stands for *floating point*).  You should look up *standard* and *custom numeric format specifiers*.

Note that I use `double.TryParse` to interpret the user's input - and if it's wrong, I give him/her another chance.  If you use `double.Parse` or `Convert.ToDouble` to do this, an incorrect entry will cause an exception to be thrown.  Users entering information in an incorrect format is hardly an *exceptional* situation, and so an exception should be avoided if possible.  The `TryParse` call signals an error with a `bool` rather than an exception.

```
double radius;
string responseFromUser;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter the radius for a circle: ");
    responseFromUser = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!double.TryParse(responseFromUser, out radius));

double diameter = 2 * radius;
double circumference = Convert.ToDouble(Math.PI * diameter);

Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}The radius of the circle is {radius:F2} units.");
Console.WriteLine($"The diameter of the circle is {diameter:F2} units.");
Console.WriteLine($"The circumference of the circle is {circumference:F2} units.");

Console.Write($"{Environment.NewLine}Press any key to continue...");

Console.ReadKey();
```

The output from this looks like:

```
Enter the radius for a circle: abc
Enter the radius for a circle: 12.333

The radius of the circle is 12.33 units.
The diameter of the circle is 24.67 units.
The circumference of the circle is 77.49 units.

Press any key to continue...
```

If you enter something with less than two decimal points, you will still get two decimal points:

```
Enter the radius for a circle: 4

The radius of the circle is 4.00 units.
The diameter of the circle is 8.00 units.
The circumference of the circle is 25.13 units.

Press any key to continue...
```